# Gitweb hosted using apache2 - Root folder can only be set in /home

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, apache2, gitweb

I am trying to make the root directory for my gitweb to be a media drive (eg. /media/pi/my_usb)

In my /etc/gitweb.conf I have the following root:

`$projectroot = "/home/git";`

With this I am able to see all repositories in this directory, which is what I want.

But when I change the root directory to (this is what I want):

`$projectroot = "/media/pi/my_usb/my_repo";`

With this at my root directory, It tells me that my directory is empty and there are no repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Mounted the usb drive so that the owner of could be changed.

Then made sure that the owner of /etc/gitweb.conf was the same as the project root (usb drive).

Now all the repositories can be detected and used.